# Error render table row with RichFaces 4.3.7 and IE8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, richfaces

when I login for the first time on my page I view the information in staggered rows in the table (rich:dataTable). As soon as I step just with the mouse pointer on these areas, the text in the cells goes to occupy its correct position.

I see the text in the header of the columns hidden by filters that are below (the correct position is on top of the filters) and a few rows back off the table but on mouse hover are shown automatically in the correct position of the row in the table.

Can you help me to solve this problem? I use RichFaces 4.3.7 and IE8.

Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I've not used RichFaces myself, but at first glance I think we need some more information. What (presumably incorrect) position is the text in before mousing over it? Can you provide screenshots or code snippets for the table?

Comment: I add a more detailed description of the problem in the question. Thanks